# Is there a way to run CLI commands from SFMC platform

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to get an export csv file placed at MC SFTP. The export file is generated from an external headless application. The team provided a github install package to be deployed using CLI commands and then run the export commands to get the csv file at local drive.
I want to accomplish the same through an automation. Is it somehow possible through SSJS?
Any advice or direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use CLI commands to place a file on Marketing Cloud. You could create FTP credentials in Marketing Cloud and use these credentials to send the file from the headless application to the Marketing Cloud FTP

Or, you can use your own FTP and add it as an external FTP location in Marketing cloud

And lastly if you use an S3 bucket for your files, you could also add it as well as an FTP location to Marketing Cloud.

You can find more information here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi Ymar, the issue is not about the file locations. The main problem is to be able to run the CLI command and when the file is exported as a result, it should be placed on any location. I can do these steps manually but want to automated it.
Exmaple CLI command: Export --porjectKey testProj --clientId testclientid --clientSecret testsecret --fullExport --out exportedfile.csv